# How to parse JSON array into separate files using Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

The PowerShell script will be provided this input file:

```json
{
    "array": [
        {
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2", 
            "field3": "value3",
            "field4": "value4",
            "field5": "value5"
        },
        {
            "field1": "value6",
            "field2": "value7", 
            "field3": "value8",
            "field4": "value9",
            "field5": "value10"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to break this up into separate json files. File1 Name: file1.json

```json
{
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": "value2", 
   "field3": "value3",
   "field4": "value4",
   "field5": "value5"
}
```

File2 Name: file2.json

```
{
   "field1": "value6",
   "field2": "value7", 
   "field3": "value8",
   "field4": "value9",
   "field5": "value10"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your attempt at solving this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a script writing service. 
We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far 
(including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck 
so that we can help with specific problems. Try `Get-Help ConvertFrom-Json -Online` and `Get-Help ConvertTo-Json -Online`. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConvertFrom-Json` to parse the input file, then use `ConvertTo-Json` to export *each individual object* in the array:

```
# import and parse input
$data = Get-Content .\path\to\input.json |ConvertFrom-Json

$count = 0
foreach($item in $data.array){
  $count++
  # export each array item as json
  $item |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content "file${count}.json"
}
```